To build a real-time turn-by-turn voice navigation mobile app with custom voice
Google Maps API is not allowed to build similar products that they already have.
Is there any other service that can achieve this?

TomTom makes a developer API for Turn by Turn navigation available for iOS and Android: https://developer.tomtom.com/
